# Should I publish findings not from my field?

Tags: publications, application

I have some findings (new but nothing ground-breaking) from my master thesis in the field of A which I could publish if I spent more time on the topic. However, my PhD and future specialization is going to be in B. So spending time in A and particularly trying to publish in the field may be a distraction from the B. When applying for postdocs and tenured positions, is any researcher/application assessor going to appreciate my publications from a different field?

I know one mathematician from Princeton. He comes to workshops and always solves some problem. He would never publish it (even if nobody else did) because it is a distraction from what he is doing. Then other participants write his ideas and publish it with his name as coauthors. On the other hand, my personal tutor told me that any publications are good as they demonstrate the researcher's independence and capability. Hence it seems, that unless a person is a top researcher in the field, publishing in other fields is not a distraction, but a plus.

Comment: How far apart are A and B? Are you referring to subdiciplines or chemistry vs physics? The Q is hard to answer without that knowledge. In general, I think published papers are counted as a plus either way.

Comment: @fileunderwater A is inductive logic programming (theoretical computer science), B is computability theory (mathematical logic). I have never seen a paper using the knowledge from those two disciplines before.